# How to partition a set of values (vector) in R

Tags: r, vector, set, data-partitioning

I'm programming in R. I've got a vector containing, let's say, 1000 values. Now let's say I want to partition these 1000 values randomly into two new sets, one containing 400 values and the other containing 600. How could I do this? I've thought about doing something like this...

```
firstset <- sample(mydata, size=400)
```

...but this doesn't partition the data (in other words, I still don't know which 600 values to put in the other set). I also thought about looping from 1 to 400, randomly removing 1 value at a time and placing it in `firstset`. This would partition the data correctly, but how to implement this is not clear to me. Plus I've been told to avoid `for` loops in R whenever possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: The point on `for` loops is not very applicable. IIRC it was an issue in S-Plus but not so much in R. As long as you allocate sufficient storage for the result (rather than grow or concatenate during each loop iteration) `for` loops can be as quick if not quicker than other native R approaches (`apply` and family) and the intention of an explicit `for` loop in code may be more readily grasped than an arcane one-liner of an `apply` call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of sampling the values, you could sample their positions.

```
positions <- sample(length(mydata), size=400)  # ucfagls' suggestion
firstset <- mydata[positions]
secondset <- mydata[-positions]
```

EDIT: ucfagls' suggestion will be more efficient (especially for larger vectors), since it avoids allocating a vector of positions in R.

Comment: The first line can be simplified to `positions <- sample(length(mydata), size=400)` so you don't need to generate the vector from which to sample. The first argument is allowed to be a positive integer. Or even to `positions <- sample(mydata, size=400)`.

Comment: Surely positions <- sample(mydata, size=400) will return actual values from mydata and not positions? You'll not be able to get the other 600. You got it right first time!

Answer (score 9):

Just randomize mydata and take the first 400 and then last 600.

```
mydata <- sample(mydata)
firstset <- mydata[1:400]
secondset <- mydata[401:1000]
```

Answer (score 4):

If `mydata` is truly a vector, one option would be:

```
split(mydata, sample(c(rep("group1", 600), rep("group2", 400))))
```

Comment: I did not know the first argument of 'sample' could be a vector. Thanks!

Comment: Additionally, this will store both subsets of the original data in one object (list), keeping the global workspace from getting cluttered.