# Randomly sample data frame into 3 groups in R

Tags: r, random

**Objective:** Randomly divide a data frame into 3 samples.

- one sample with 60% of the rows
- other two samples with 20% of the rows
- samples should not have duplicates of others (i.e. sample without replacement).

Here's a clunky solution:

```
allrows <- 1:nrow(mtcars)

set.seed(7)
trainrows <- sample(allrows, replace = F, size = 0.6*length(allrows))
test_cvrows <- allrows[-trainrows]
testrows <- sample(test_cvrows, replace=F, size = 0.5*length(test_cvrows))
cvrows <- test_cvrows[-which(test_cvrows %in% testrows)]

train <- mtcars[trainrows,]
test <- mtcars[testrows,]
cvr <- mtcars[cvrows,]
```

There must be something easier, perhaps in a package.  `dplyr` has the `sample_frac` function, but that seems to target a single sample, not a split into multiple.

*Close, but not quite the answer to this question:
[Random Sample with multiple probabilities in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002101/random-sample-with-multiple-probabilities-in-r?lq=1)*

Comment: This may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3911586/1191259

Comment: @Frank that is a pretty slick answer.  I'd rather not have to hard code the partition rows though, I'm going to keep it in mind for future use.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you need the partitioning to be exact?  If not,

```
set.seed(7)
ss <- sample(1:3,size=nrow(mtcars),replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.6,0.2,0.2))
train <- mtcars[ss==1,]
test <- mtcars[ss==2,]
cvr <- mtcars[ss==3,]
```

should do it.

Or, as @Frank says in comments, you can `split()` the original data to keep them as elements of a list:

```
mycars <- setNames(split(mtcars,ss), c("train","test","cvr"))
```

Comment: I'd use `split` to not lose track of 'em `mycars = setNames(split(mtcars,ss), c("train","test","cvr"))`

Comment: Partitioning does not need to be exact.  This works and I like @Frank 's addendum.

Comment: If you want an exact partitioning, replace the `ss` line with: `ss <- sample(rep(1:3, diff(floor(nrow(yourdataset) * c(0, 0.6, 0.8, 1)))))`

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest solution (especially for larger samples), but it works.

```
n = nrow(mtcars)
#use different rounding for differet sizes/proportions
times =rep(1:3,c(0.6*n,0.2*n,0.2*n))
ntimes = length(times)
if (ntimes < n)
    times = c(times,sample(1:3,n-ntimes,prob=c(0.6,0.2,0.2),replace=FALSE))
sets = sample(times)
df1 = mtcars[sets==1,]
df2 = mtcars[sets==2,]
df3 = mtcars[sets==3,]
```

Comment: A simpler `times` might be `findInterval(1:n, n*c(0,.6,.8))`

Answer (score 0):

**Options without replacement**

Using caret package.

```
library(caret)

inTrain <- createDataPartition(mtcars$mpg, p = 0.6, list = FALSE)
train <- mtcars[inTrain, ]
inTest <- createDataPartition(mtcars$mpg[-inTrain], list = FALSE)
test <- mtcars[-inTrain,][inTest, ]
cvr <- mtcars[-inTrain,][-inTest, ]
```

Base package.

```
## splitData
# y column of data to create split on
# p list of percentage split
splitData <- function(y, p = c(0.5)){
  if(sum(p) > 1){
    stop("sum of p cannot exceed 1")
  }

  rows <- 1:length(y)

  res <- list()

  n_sample = round(length(rows) * p)
  for( size in n_sample){
    inSplit <-  sample.int(length(rows), size)
    res <- c(res, list(rows[inSplit]))
    rows <- rows[-inSplit]
  }

  if(sum(as.matrix(p)) < 1){
    res <- c(res, list(rows))
  }

  res
}

split_example_2 <- splitData(mtcars$mpg, p = c(0.6, 0.2))
split_example_3 <- splitData(mtcars$mpg)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get exact and reproducible numbers for each group (split as close to the proportions as you can achieve, bearing in mind the group sizes must be whole numbers), rather than allow the group sizes to vary randomly each time you perform your random split, try:

```
sample_size <- nrow(mtcars)
set_proportions <- c(Training = 0.6, Validation = 0.2, Test = 0.2)
set_frequencies <- diff(floor(sample_size * cumsum(c(0, set_proportions))))
mtcars$set <- sample(rep(names(set_proportions), times = set_frequencies))
```

Then you can split into a list of dataframes simply by

```
mtcars <- split(mtcars, mtcars$set)
```

so e.g. the dataframe for the validation set is now accessed as `mtcars$Validation`, or alternatively you can split into separate data frames as:

```
mtcars_train <- mtcars[mtcars$set == "Training", ]
mtcars_validation <- mtcars[mtcars$set == "Validation", ]
mtcars_test <- mtcars[mtcars$set == "Test", ]
```

In some cases, like this one, you can't split the data exactly 60%, 20%, 20% but this method guarantees the sizes of the two 20% sets shouldn't be more than one apart from each other:

```
> set_frequencies
  Training Validation       Test 
        19          6          7
```

Check it has worked as expected:

```
> table(mtcars$set)

      Test   Training Validation 
         7         19          6
```

(Based on the answer by Ben Bolker and the comment by liori.)